SELECT finds one row - UPDATE using the same WHERE clause updates two rows?
I'm updating a value
UPDATE sales..cardtype
SET accountingnumber = 1300
WHERE cardtype = 40

On most of the servers this returned the expected one row.
This was to be expected since Cardtype is the PK for this table.
However, some stores returned two rows to be updated:
(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

Any advice why this would happen?
I double checked some of those servers and their PK isn't "broken", there isn't two lines of this cardtype.. so.. anyone know why some of the servers tell me two rows were changed?

If you see extra "(1 row affected)" message this will be coming from a different statement. Probably in a trigger - also having actual execution plan enabled in SSMS can cause this message

A TRIGGER on your table that doesn't have NOCOUNT set to ON.
